# Why does sulfur concrete require no cement?

Tags: civil-engineering

Sulfur concrete only uses sulfur as a binding agent then an aggregate. Why does it not use cement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The molten sulfur is the "cement".  I understand that hundreds of years ago sulfur concrete was occasionally used. In the 70's , Amoco experimented with sulfur + asphalt concretes. They had excellent properties but were too expensive.

Comment: I came here looking for people that know a bit about concrete,  who might be able to help us answer this question, on the brand new Materials Stack Exchange: https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/493/5